# Is a question about installing Apache modules on topic here?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic

I have a question to ask about installing the mod_wsgi module for Apache on Centos 7, so that I can write a python web server. I wanted to make sure it would be on topic here before asking it though. As far as I can tell, this seems to be the best place for it.

Comment: Yes, and if you're lucky, [Graham Dumpleton](http://serverfault.com/users/10639/graham-dumpleton) himself might answer it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, go for it.

Make sure you read the help section so that you understand what our expectations are. We don't do tutorials. The best SF questions are well-researched, reasonably-scoped, and well-articulated.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Given my current knowledge level on the topic, I think I've done about as much research into it as I can while trying to pin down my issue. I'll be sure to spend some time getting it well-articulated.

Comment: You'll be fine. You're clearly on the right track of trying to be intentional about asking in the right place, etc. Don't fret about it - post the question and as long as you don't come off as a "help vampire" (someone who is coming here to have us do their job for them, never to return), you'll be fine.